# Copying bib file manually in document

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am writing a IEEE paper. I have a separate `.tex` file and `.bib` file. The instructions mention that

> "When submitting the document source (.tex) file to external parties,
>   it is strongly recommended that the BIBTEX .bbl file be manually
>   copied into the document (within the traditional LATEX bibliography
>   environment) so as not to depend on external files to generate the
>   bibliography and to prevent the possibility of changes occurring
>   therein"

How can I manually copy into the same file such that references are generated ?

Comment: Replace the `\bibliography{...}` command with the conntents of the bbl that is generate by bibtex.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I delete "\bibliography{IEEEabrv,name1}" and in its place copy the contents of .bib file

Comment: The title of your question is wrong. The instruction says to copy the `.bbl` not the `.bib`. The .bbl is a simple text file, open it and copy its content.

Comment: Are both of them different? I have written the references in BibTex format in .bib file?. What do I need to do now to ensure that the above instruction in followed ?

Comment: Why don't you open both files and compare them?

Comment: .bbl file doesn't open. I am using TexStudio. Is a specific software needed to open .bbl file ?

Comment: It is a simple text file. Simply open it through the file menu of texstudio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us start with a simple MWE (package `filecontents` is only used to have TeX code and bib file together in one compiling MWE) `mwe.tex`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@article{feynman,
  title     = {Very High-Energy Collisions of Hadrons},
  author    = {Richard P. Feynman},
  journal   = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume    = {23},
  issue     = {24},
  pages     = {1415--1417},
  year      = {1969},
  month     = {Dec},
  doi       = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  url       = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.1415},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

It compiles to the following page:

[image: resulting page]

Now open the directory with the explorer or just use the terminal and search for file `mwe.bbl`. You can open it simply with any editor, for example `notepad`:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{Goossens}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1 edition, 1994.

\bibitem{adams}
Douglas Adams.
\newblock {\em The Restaurant at the End of the Universe}.
\newblock The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Pan Macmillan, 1980.

\bibitem{feynman}
Richard~P. Feynman.
\newblock Very high-energy collisions of hadrons.
\newblock {\em Phys. Rev. Lett.}, 23:1415--1417, Dec 1969.

\end{thebibliography}
```

It contains the needed information for your tex file to build the bibliography.

Copy now `mwe.tex` to `mwe-a.tex` and change it as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt} % <==========================================

\begin{thebibliography}{1} % <==========================================

\bibitem{Goossens}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock {\em The LaTeX Companion}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1 edition, 1994.

\bibitem{adams}
Douglas Adams.
\newblock {\em The Restaurant at the End of the Universe}.
\newblock The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. Pan Macmillan, 1980.

\bibitem{feynman}
Richard~P. Feynman.
\newblock Very high-energy collisions of hadrons.
\newblock {\em Phys. Rev. Lett.}, 23:1415--1417, Dec 1969.

\end{thebibliography} % <===============================================

\end{document}
```

As you can see I deleted the bib file in the mwe and changed the code marked with `<======`. The bib file is not longer needed, because the inserted `.bbl` part contains all informations needed. I also commented the bibliography style (not needed with environment `thebibliography`).

Now compile this code to the result:

[image: resulting page]

Compare it with the first result: no difference!