# Multiple documents using one .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

So I have a document and a bib  file for it. this works perfectly. Now I need to hand the document in a specific way, let me give you an example:

suppose I name a latex file "FunctionalaAnalysis" and the respective bib file as "References". Now, my lecturer wants the document to be named "name number- type of document" (eg Bob, smith 178 - article)

I thought of saving the two documents (above in the example) as a new document but things didn't work, any ideas?

Edit:

The code that I used for my first file was:

```
\addbibresource{References.bib}
```

which works

however when I save the same document as a duplicate with a different name it doesn't work.

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6350) The top-level auxiliary file: bob, smith 178 - Report.aux The style file: biblatex.bst I couldn't open database file bob.bib ---line 3 of file bob, smith 178 - Report.aux : \bibdata{bob : ,_smith_178_-_Report-blx,References} I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no database files---while reading file bob, smith 178  - Report.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "biblatex-control" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "serre1977linear" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "webb2016course" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "steinberg2011representation" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "luong2009fourier" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "diaconis1988group" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "chebolu2012representations" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "lyons1996random" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "levin2009markov" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "bollobas2013modern" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "woess2000random" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "meier2008groups" Biblatex version: 3.3 (There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, i.e., what "didn't work"? Do you get an error message? Or is the problem that you are only allowed to hand in one file whereas you have two files (the main document and the bibliography file)? In that case you can try https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396335/copying-bib-file-manually-in-document.

Comment: no, the problem is that I want to use the same bib file for two separate, but identical documents(the name of one the documents is altered to require what my lecturer wants). but this is not working;

Comment: Ok, that should be no problem, just use `\bibliography{References}` (with BibTeX) or `\addbibresource{References.bib}` (with BibLaTeX) in both files.

Comment: I did that. it didn't work

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I was ill. yes I get an error message

Comment: No problem, I hope you feel better now. What did the error message say exactly?

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, I am better now. its not an "error" per se rather the bibliography doesn't show up

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the code that you use to add the bibliography to your documents as part of your question. You can use the `edit` button below the post to edit the post. Also, which editor do you use? Maybe there are warnings being displayed somewhere? Also the contents of the log files (specifically the bibliography logs) can be useful.

Comment: I have edited. I use Tex maker. yes when I run the Latex -> bib -> Latex -> Latex on the second document I get an error on the bib file

Comment: edited the full error message when I run the bib file

Comment: The problem is the whitespace in the name of an intermediate file (the `-blx` file). It is a limitation of BibTeX that it cannot process files with spaces. However, it seems you use BibLaTeX with BibTeX backend, is that correct? In that case you could try to switch to the `biber` backend which may solve the present issue.

Comment: Besides that, what does your lecturer require exactly? The LaTeX source, or the compiled pdf? Does he want to compile the document himself and/or make changes? Maybe you can include the precompiled `.bbl` file instead of the `.bib` file?

Comment: I tried with the biber backend, the problem still persists. If its a big problem, I'm not going to change it as this is wasting a lot of time aha!